# Proving undecidability of a language with mapping reductions

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, reductions, undecidability

I'm referring to questions like this one:
[Mapping reduction to show NeverHalt is undecidable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19055/mapping-reduction-to-show-neverhalt-is-undecidable)

I understand with Turing reductions, you have to use oracle calls of the unknown language you're trying to prove is undecidable to solve a known undecidable language.

However, with mapping reductions, am I right in assuming these calls aren't needed? In addition, in the link provided, the solution pseudocode says

```
For input x:
  Simulate M for input w
    if it accepts, loop
    if it rejects accept x
```

How can you say "if it accepts"? How can you determine this, what if it loops forever and this is never found out? Why can you make such statements with a mapping reduction but not with Turing reductions? Could I make a statement like "if M halts on w, do ...". I mentioned this to my teaching assistant and he said you can't make any statements like these unless you're accessing an oracle and doing a during reduction, but I see loads of examples which seem to show otherwise. Hopefully this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when the context of the statement "if $M$ accepts $x$" is in a loop simulating the execution of $M$ on $x$, we just mean to say that if the simulation stopped and $M$ accepted/rejected then do something, otherwise just continue simulating (the more precise way of writing this would be to say "if $M$ accepted after $t$ steps then...").

Your pseudocode doesn't do anything magical, it simply checks **at a specific point of the simulation** whether or not $M$ already accepted/rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So likewise, can you say something like "if M halts on x" without accessing the halt oracle? Is that fine to do with mapping reductions? Can you do that with turing reductions as well, or can you only make such statements if you're accessing the halt oracle

Comment: Since the halting problem is not decidable, there isn't an always halting procedure that would allow you to check whether or not $M$ halts on $x$ for arbitrary $M,x$. If you had a halting oracle then this would have been easy, simply query it on $(M,x)$.

Comment: So how come you're allowed to make a statement like "if M accepts x" but not "if M halts on x"?

Comment: Both are ok in the context I described, you can always simulate $M$ and at any given point check if it already accepted/halted. The problem arises if you use this as a command which supposedly always returns an answer.

Comment: So just to confirm, whenever in these questions you construct a new TM M and simulate M on an input x, you're allowed to make statements like 'if M accepts x/if M halts on x" etc?

Comment: It's not that "if you simulate you're allowed to write X", it's what we mean when we write it in this context. Suppose you are debugging a program, then at any point you can stop and ask something about its behavior so far. This is exactly what we're doing here, during the simulation, after each step we stop and ask ourselves, "has M already accepted/rejected/halted/wrote something/behaved in some kind of way", and if not we just continue to simulate it another step.

Comment: Ah I see thank you. So was the teaching assistant wrong then when he said you can't make such statements? Since I was writing it in that context

Comment: I have no problem with the pseudocode above, someone else might require you to be more specific, e.g. loop for $t\in\mathbb{N}$, and inside the loop execute $M$ on $x$ for $t$ steps and then do something if $M$ halted/accepted.